# react-native run-ios not working

Tags: javascript, android, ios, node.js, react-native

I'm following the course in [this lesson](https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-react-native-and-redux-course/learn/v4/t/lecture/5740472?start=0)

```
Versions are:
  npm 5.4.2
  homebrew 1.3.3
  react-native-cli: 2.0.1
  react-native: 0.48.4
  watchman 4.9.0
  node v6.6.0
```

I've ran the commands:

```
admin@admin  ~/Documents/ReactNativeLearning  react-native init albums
This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in /Users/admin/Documents/ReactNativeLearning/albums
Using yarn v1.0.2
Installing react-native...
yarn add v1.0.2
info No lockfile found.
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
warning connect@2.30.2: connect 2.x series is deprecated
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning "react-native@0.48.4" has unmet peer dependency "react@16.0.0-alpha.12".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 496 new dependencies.

✨  Done in 25.56s.
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _node_module_register
  Referenced from: /Users/admin/node_modules/bufferutil/build/Release/bufferutil.node
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _node_module_register
  Referenced from: /Users/admin/node_modules/bufferutil/build/Release/bufferutil.node
  Expected in: flat namespace

[1]    12606 abort      react-native init albums
 ✘ admin@admin  ~/Documents/ReactNativeLearning  react-native run-ios
Command `run-ios` unrecognized. Make sure that you have run `npm install` and that you are inside a react-native project.
 ✘ admin@admin  ~/Documents/ReactNativeLearning  cd albums
 admin@admin  ~/Documents/ReactNativeLearning/albums  react-native run-ios
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _node_module_register
  Referenced from: /Users/admin/node_modules/bufferutil/build/Release/bufferutil.node
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _node_module_register
  Referenced from: /Users/admin/node_modules/bufferutil/build/Release/bufferutil.node
  Expected in: flat namespace

[1]    12632 abort      react-native run-ios
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing an `npm install` in your Project folder and then do `react-native run-ios`

Comment: Tried it check this out: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/6ab41a6fc3499030fcf228ef34317c35/raw/8628a9bb7e27f053ce0398dabb99e49e1dc16db7/gistfile1.txt

Comment: Is this the first time you init a project using react-native cli bro?

Comment: If it is the first time, maybe the ```react-native``` cli wasn't installed properly. Try uninstalling and then installing the cli again.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working ​it turns out that I was using a different version of node (v6.6.0). So I installed nvm, and upgraded my node. Now it's working!

Also I tried using create-react-native-app instead of react-native init. The same problem appeared. Be sure to update all the necessary tools and check your node version.